# Chrome UDP socket server sendTo other hosts than localhost returns -109 error code

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm using the chrome network API to open an UDP socket that should both listen and send data (server and client). That's why i'm using the server way with `bind`/`sendTo`/`recvFrom`.

However, I am not able to send data to other hosts than local hosts: see my example below. The code error `-109` [corresponds](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/base/net_error_list.h&l=119-121) to `ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`.

```
chrome.socket.create('udp', function(socketInfo) {

  var socketId = socketInfo.socketId;

  chrome.socket.bind(socketId, '127.0.0.1', 3008, function(s) {

    chrome.socket.getInfo(socketId, function(info) {
      console.log(info);
      // {connected: false, localAddress: "127.0.0.1", localPort: 3008, socketType: "udp"} 
    });

    var arr = new Uint8Array(1);
    arr[0] = 123;
    var ab = arr.buffer;

    chrome.socket.sendTo(socketId, ab, "127.0.0.1", 3007, function(sendResult) {
      console.log("sendTo", sendResult);
      //sendTo {bytesWritten: 1}
    });
    chrome.socket.sendTo(socketId, ab, "google.com", 3007, function(sendResult) {
      console.log("sendTo", sendResult);
      //sendTo {bytesWritten: -109}
    });
  });
});
```

My permissions are the less restrictive ones: `udp-send-to` and `udp-bind`.

Using the `connect`/`write` way works but that's not what I want achieve, since i'm trying to open a socket than is server and client at same time.

Any idea ?

Comment: The [docs say](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html#type-WriteInfo) that if `bytesWritten` is negative, it is an error code.  Have you investigated what `-109` means?

Comment: Oh yes, I added a line about it in the question. Thx

Comment: Are trying to connect to port 3007 on "google.com"? There doesn't seem to be such port open.

Comment: Nobody tries to connect to google.com:3007. Since it's UDP, there is no "connection" and you don't care about port open or not. FYI, there is nothing listening on 127.0.0.1:3007, and still !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make that run by binding the socket on `0.0.0.0` rather than `127.0.0.1`.

```
chrome.socket.bind(socketId, '0.0.0.0', 3008, function(s) {
  //.. and so on
});
```

That was maybe what @EJP meant in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197460/1501565). I found the solution by browsing [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178488).

Comment: No 'maybe' about it. It is +exactly* what I meant, and it is also what I said. 0.0.0.0 is the default.

Answer (score 1):

If you bind your socket to 127.0.0.1 it can only send and receive to the localhost. So don't do that. Use the default.

Comment: Why it can only send to the localhost ? Where is it stated ? What do you mean by use the default ?

Comment: @alexstrat Because that is the *meaning* of binding to localhost. That is the meaning of localhost. It is an IP address that only works within the localhost. It isn't visible outside.